# Superman "Kryptonian" traits vs powers

Tags: dc, superman, powers, krypton, kryptonite

I was wondering. Most of Superman's powers are a result of his exposure to a yellow sun and get negated when he is exposed to Kryptonite.

Are there any Kryptonian traits that are superhuman in any sense and thus not negated by Kryptonite? That is, things such as improved intelligence, endurance, reflexes or any other kind of trait which is a result of him being Kryptonian instead of a result of the yellow sun?

Answer (score 4):

Derived from the *Man of Steel* film we can deduce or speculate upon a number of non-power traits:

- Atmospheric Adaptation - The film positively establishes that an adult human woman from Earth could not survive in Krypton's atmosphere.  By contrast, adult Kryptonians can breath both Krypton's atmosphere and Earth's atmosphere without distress.  Although a baby Kryptonian raised on Earth experiences respiratory distress, one can adapt until it is not an issue; and that same being exposed to Kryptonian atmosphere as an adult experiences only *temporary* distress before adapting and awakening without *respiratory* issues.  This means Kryptonians are inherently able to cope with a broader range of atmospheric conditions than humans.
- Slow Aging - Zod chronicles their search for Kal-El as taking 33 years.  If you look at Faora as equivalent to a human woman in her late 20s or early 30s and add another three decades so that she is in her 50s or 60s, it is plain as day that she has not aged like a normal human being on Earth.  This might be attributable to a Kryptonian trait.
- Genetically Engineered - Kryptonian society by the events in *Man of Steel* was completely dependent on genetically engineered populace.  Therefore it would be reasonable to assume Kryptonian traits include any which you would select for in a eugenic vision of perfection.  For example, absence of genetic diseases or selection for long life, sharp minds, and sound bodies.  There are many benefits to a strong muscular body irrespective of exercise, so Kryptonians may produce more myostatin than humans; allowing for athleticism without effort and addressing the boring question of how Superman could possibly achieve his body without resistance training.
- Genetic Memory - There are clues that Kryptonians can perhaps pass along information genetically.  Clark as a child wears a red cape, not because he is aware of Krypton, but because his blood inclines him towards it.  Similarly, Clark is drawn towards the Scout Ship's arctic location subconsciously.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend heavily on **which version** of Superman continuity Kryptonian we are speaking of. I'll try to cover as many as possible to facilitate ease of understanding, but there are a *lot* of aspects to touch on and time periods to cover.

## Pre-Crisis

The oldest versions of Superman (from his 1939 inception) was *not* powered by the sun at all; his physical abilities arose purely out of his *very* different physical structure. The original 1939 *Action Comics* issues offered  *Scientific Explanation for Superman's Amazing Strength!* It spoke to the differences between "earth men" and those of Krypton. They can be seen in the page below, jumping inhuman distances on their own planet as the "Scientific Explanation" is given:

[image]

An over-simplification of the science, yes, but still some basis of physical difference. Within that first year, Superman showcased superhuman (but NOT *God like* ) strength enough to hold up buildings, leap between 1/8 to a full mile, less restriction by Earth's gravity, immunity from all illnesses, near endless stamina, speed greater than that of bullet trains and even some bullets, resistance to great forces (heat, cold, pressure, even electricity), had natural telescopic and *some minor* form of X-ray vision, and only *limited* effects to various poison gases. He was also said to be near physically perfect, in terms of his body's balance and symmetry.

All of *these* were attributed to the differences in his *physical* Kryptonian structure; his people had "Evolved" to near "physical perfection."

This would generally mean that on a physical and genetic level, there were already different. Krypton's greater gravity and harsher environment would only *enhance* these effects, because back then, even on Krypton,  those aliens were *Still* superhuman, to a degree.

By the 1950s when Superman's powers had grown to the point where he could nominally shape shift, fly, move so fast he could break the *Time barrier,* shoot heat from his eyes, tow whole planets on his back and shrug off nuclear blasts... well, suffice it to say the "because of gravity" explanation didn't *quite*  cover everything. Hence the writers used a combination of Gravity, Evolution and an inexhaustible power source (the sun) affecting his body to provide his array of powers.

[image]

Now these were all **Pre-Crisis** versions, and even the 1978 movie version (more or less) fell in line with this. Being it was 40 years later, just *how* advance Krypton was (the use of psychic crystals as technology, for instance) was added, but it still touched upon a number of important *physical* differences which were traits to Kryptonians.

Note the specifics of what they pointed out, almost all of which had *nothing* to do with the solar radiation/Photonucleic effect:

1. Lara pointed out that comparatively, Earth is "primitive; *thousands* of years behind us." This is likely a *gross* **understatement* on Lara's part, considering most Scientific evidence shows that the physical and behavioral traits shared by all earth people originated from apelike ancestors and evolved over a period of approximately **six million years.** So I'm guessing by "Thousands" of years, she meant *multiple hundreds* if not at least *dozens* of thousands, and was speaking more to their *society* and technology, rather than their physical or genetic evolution.
2. "Their atmosphere will sustain him". This points to differences in the planetary atmospherics (oxygen and other gases compositions, density, pressure, etc) but that the planets are just similar enough where it will allow him to breath without difficulty.
3. "He will *defy* their gravity."  Can't be certain if this speaks to his normal movement, or his power of flight. Either way, gravity tends to have an impact on physiognomy, as well as *molecular density,* which would add to any Kryptonian's natural durability, speed, agility and energy processing on a "lower gravity" planet, even if their internal and cellular structures were basically identical.
4. "His molecular density will make him strong." Here is a basic principle; essentially, where as most human tissues may be comparable to water, a Kryptonian tissue would, on the lower end, be comparable to osmium, the densest material known to man. This is just how both races naturally *are,* due to their evolution. This would naturally make a Kryptonian of equal size and weight to a human the stronger of the two, if all their tissues corresponded to that density scale.

It should be noted these were all Pre-Crisis versions of superman; the latest versions to fall in line with the combination GES (Gravity, Evolution, Sunlight) answer would be the **New 52** version, *and* to a lesser extent the **Man of Steel 2013** version. He speaks to the "harshness" of Krypton's environment, and gives a rudimentary rundown of the differences in Kryptonian and human bodies. *NOTE:* the mere fact that they had been "Exploring or expanding" into other worlds for hundreds of thousands of years indicate that, in terms of technology and society, Kryptonians were *already* a space faring race before mankind on earth had even reached its final *homo sapien* evolutionary phase.

When Clark asks "Why am I so different from them?"  Jor El basically offers the GES suggestion:

Coming to the ***Post-Crisis*** continuity, things get a bit more difficult.

### Post Crisis Versions

Baically any version of the character that came out after the 1986 *Crisis* event. This is significant because explanations of Superman/Kryptonian powers and abilities becomes somewhat more complex, if involving fewer elements. In this version, Krypton was only about 3 times the size of Earth, so any gravitational adaptive advantages were negligible; Kryptonians now got **all** of their extra normal abilities from the sun. This also meant that any extra speed, agility or durability boost which came from enhanced molecular density were now negated, as their tissues were basically identical to those of earth humans. While the society was still more advanced by several thousand years, they were a cold, isolationist, logic-based society. It was thought that the didn't "evolve" to be super in other environments, but at least *Some* of their advancement came via experiments with cloning some millennia before and centuries of bio-tech advancements.

The total solar absorption ability was stated by Jor-El himself in the very first comic:

[image]

The key differences given the physical structure of Kryptonians and Humans here (which, oddly enough, are not only traits, but also basically then affects his powers) were set in the way their cellular matrices acted, and in the organelles that allowed them to absorb and store solar radiation. This came down to Kryptonians being different from humans on a **DNA** level. This was verified in a *JLA* comic, *Duel Identities* ; basically, an alien force had sperated the JLA members with dual identities (Batman, Green Lantern, Flash, Martian Manhunter, Plastic man, and of course Superman) in *Two separate beings,* one being the super powered hero, the other their human persona. The Clark Kent here had *No* Kryptonian DNA, to the point of where the Justice League teleporter didn't even recognize him. The Superman persona confirmed this by X-ray scanning him:

[image]

In this case, its kind of hard to split the "kryptonian traits" from the "super powers," because without the alien DNA, there is basically no difference. From my own research, however, I have found that there may be some Kryptonian "traits" which differ specially to Human structure which *provide* the basis for super human powers. This is all speculation, but it is backed up somewhat by what we see in the comics. I already wrote on this in another question, so I'm going to paraphrase some of it here, as it does apply.

In general, the main difference comes down to *a highly advanced Kyrptonian physiology, that is, in some ways, deeply different from that of earth humans.* It may be *humanoid* in appearance, yes, but thanks to being *millions of years* more evolved, it's not "terrestrial human" in any fundamental way, other than its exterior design. This in and of itself is *also* significant;  for a human to evolve to maintain even a *semi* human form under possibly *thousands* of times Earth's gravity (which, by all scientific reasoning, would either make such aliens either more squat, shorter, and more powerfully built, or at the very least with a tissue more resembling *diamond* or rock than flesh) on top of possible energy, atmospheric, and EM radiation differences, their DNA would have to be **hard wired** to look even *remotely* human.

That being said, these traits which Krypton natives possess which humans don't, are likely as follows:

**1. A more evolved form of muscle cells and tissues, combining both slow-twitch AND fast-twitch properties.** These "pink muscles" would allow Kryptonians to produce a greater amount of force, *without tiring* , and for far longer periods. They would also probably have a naturally higher number of mitochondria [the cellular powerhouses] which would produce greater contraction ratings in each fiber.  In other words, if there was *no yellow sun and equal gravity,* and Superman was placed against an earthling of equal size, height, weight and mass, his muscles would *still* work, on average, 10-20 times *better* and longer, making him an average of possibly 20 times stronger.

**2. A cell structure that more efficiently copies itself,** allowing the cells to flush toxins, renew themselves and make perfect clone cells without [or at least with a highly retarded rate of] degradation. This would mean *every cell in his body,* even *without* a yellow sun, produces less waste chemicals from break down, and more quickly reproduces/ regenerates from damage. This would account for Kryptonians aging more slowly than humans, as well as providing a sort of "healing factor" similar to lizards or star fish.

**3. A corded muscle structure.**  Most human muscle is smooth and flat; it's possible Kryptonians have muscles which are linked like braided ropes or chains, meaning the fibers are entwined in a latices pattern. This phenomenon is real, and can be seen in  other bipeds (simians), who, pound for pound, are stronger than humans of equal weight. This would naturally make them stronger and more durable, physically.

**4. Adaptive antibodies in his immune system.**  A Kryptonian's immune system would *need* to be more evolved to be able to "resists poisons" as they do. It's likely that the harsher Kryptonian environment produced "super bugs" which their immune system developed normal defenses for, so anything from this planet wouldn't even register as a threat.

**5. A more advanced chromosomal structure.** With only a 10% difference between the DNA of a virus and of a human, we are *radically* different in physical form and function. So it's not illogical to think Kryptonian physiology varies on a *chromosomal* level, in terms of possible number or new genes structures. These chromosomes would account for the organelles in Kryptonian cells that use solar radiation to enhance tissues and produce even MORE physical power. Chromosomal differences also explains why Kryptonians simply *can't* sire children with earthers; we're too different even at the genetic level.

**6. A more advanced Brain/ neuro-synaptic structure.** This accounts for a Kryptonian's greater memory, senses, and faster nervous system, *and* attributes in part to strength and speed; their nerves would *need* to fire faster to power more evolved muscle tissue at a greater rate. This likely also means that they largely perceive everything around them in "slower motion" than most humans. So even without the sun, they'd likely still move and think up to 90 times *faster* than a human.

**8. Greater abundance of stem or progenitor cells, which would also mean greater capacity for developed sensory cells.**

**9. Actual development of new regions in the brain, or greater access to all regions.**  The prefrontal cortex is the central structure in the human brain which accounts for our higher development compared to most other species. Taking it a step further in Kryptonian bodies, their brains may have developed regions which can allow for psionic abilities, such as telepathy, eidetic memory, and even limited telekinesis.

**10. Personal gravitational control organ.**  Lex Luthor theorized this in **Superman: Birthright,** and it makes sense. It's basically some type of internal structure, like lymph nodes, which control a personal gravity field would allow him to [a] fly at will with enough energy to control it, [b] maintain his molecular density on this or any other lighter planet [c] explain why his body "instinctively" stays "planted" on earth, as opposed to Superman moving on earth the way a human moves on the moon, and why his muscle doesn't waste away while being on this planet.

All of these would be latent, normal abilities ANY Kryptonian would have on their planet, just on comparatively FAR LOWER levels, as a result of *Krypton's* gravity, environment, atmosphere and cosmology....as well as perhaps a comparatively quicker rate of their race's evolution weeding out many of their weaknesses. So whereas it took our species 6 million years to evolve, Kryptonains could do that in 1/10 of the time. Krypton was purposed to be 11 Billion years old prior to its destruction, so even if they *did* evolve at the same rate as humans, they had almost *double that time* to reach their peak and go beyond than humans did on our barely 5 billion year old planet.

So, on a super-giant world like Kyrpton, which could easily be 50 times earth's size or more, and theoretically made of even heavier materials.... these "physical traits" are fairly common. While "super", yes, they are by no means *God-like* due to the planet itself "limiting" their ability, and the lack of a super-empowering Yellow sun. If on the other hand, they *had* a yellow sun on Krypton, their physiology *would* be super energized, but perhaps still affected by the gravity & environment of the world, making them....mmmm, perhaps 1/3 - 1/10 as strong as Superman in an Earth environment is.

Again, though, this is mostly conjecture.